# Three.js specific imports failing, possibly Webpack's fault

Tags: javascript, webpack, import, three.js, create-react-app

*Disclaimer: I'm using `create-react-app` and `three.js v0.99.0`.*

I'm trying to import specific three.js modules, since importing straight from the root module includes the entire library in the bundle, which is 0.5MB uncompressed. Most direct `src/` imports work fine, however when importing Geometry, AKA changing this:

```
import { Geometry } from "three";
```

to this:

```
import { Geometry } from "three/src/core/Geometry";
```

The line on my graph that it was drawing no longer appears, and there's no error messages. In addition, importing the WebGLRendered straight from `src/` caused the whole thing to implode:

```
import { WebGLRenderer } from "three"; // from this
import { WebGLRenderer } from "three/src/renderers/WebGLRenderer"; // to this
```

with the error:

```
WebGLIndexedBufferRenderer.js:14 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'type' of undefined
    at WebGLIndexedBufferRenderer.setIndex (WebGLIndexedBufferRenderer.js:14)
    at WebGLRenderer.renderBufferDirect (WebGLRenderer.js:505)
    at renderObject (WebGLRenderer.js:932)
    at renderObjects (WebGLRenderer.js:913)
    at WebGLRenderer.render (WebGLRenderer.js:790)
    at SceneManager.js:75
    ...
```

I checked the definitions of these modules in the three.js library, and they are literally copy pasted between `three.module.js` and `src/`, so there's no code differences I can find. However, one thing I did notice is that if I import both and print them, Webpack seems to be transpiling the one I import from `src/`:

```
ƒ Geometry() {
  Object.defineProperty(this, 'id', {
    value: geometryId += 2
  });
  this.uuid = _math_Math_js__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_10__["_Math"].generateUUID();
  ...
```

as opposed to:

```
ƒ Geometry() {
  Object.defineProperty(this, 'id', {
    value: geometryId += 2
  });
  this.uuid = _Math.generateUUID();
  ...
```

is it possible that `create-react-app`'s Webpack is messing with imports that are within a `src/` folder, thus making them not work despite the source code being identical? If so, is there a way to make it only transpile code within MY `src/` folder, and not the 3rd partiy modules'?

Answer (score 0):

It's probably a babel issue. By default, babel won't transpile anything in `node_modules`, however you're importing from the ES6 source, so you need to force it to transpile these. In your webpack config, you should have a rule (in module.rules) for js(x) files that looks something like

```
{
  test: /\.jsx?$/,
  use: 'babel-loader'
}
```

add a custom exclude that will exclude everything in `node_modules` *except* the `three` files, i.e.

```
{
  test: /\.jsx?$/,
  exclude: /node_modules\/(?!three)/,
  use: 'babel-loader'
}
```

Comment: Since we're using `create-react-app` we don't have direct access to `wepback.config.js` unless we eject it, which we haven't done. Would I have to eject it to make that config change?

Comment: I'm not familiar with ejecting from `create-react-app` - can you eject it to test out the idea and reverse the ejection if it doesn't work?

Comment: Tried to eject to test it, and literally 1000 things broke, couldn't even get it running :( Will keep trying.